# defmethod/ multi : clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to:

Tags: clojure

I was try to run following code ,but it turns out to be an error which I don't understand . Pls kindly enlighten me which part is wrong ?

Code:

```
(defmulti test_mul
  (fn [x y] (class y)))

(defmethod test_mul String [x y]
  (str x  y " String here"))

(defmethod test_mul java.lang.Number [x y]
  (str x y " Number here"))


(test_mul 3 4)
```

Error shows:

```
clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (2) passed to:    core$eval6599$fn
AFn.java:437 clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity
AFn.java:43 clojure.lang.AFn.invoke
MultiFn.java:231 clojure.lang.MultiFn.invok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I open a new repl and enter your code, it runs perfectly fine, producing the following output:

```
"34 number here"
```

I suspect, therefore, that you have something in your repl session that is causing the error.

HTH

Cheers

Comment: seems something wrong with lighttable, code works fine with my repl as well.

Comment: i have just downloaded light table 0.6.6 and it runs fine in an instarepl in there (i had to remind myself how to turn on the instarepl :) , i more often use nightcode)

Comment: Redefining multimethods is a more tricky than just re-evaluating them. This has happened to me a few times, and it's normally because I had an old definition hanging around.